# Use outer function with FUN="-" in Python

Tags: python, r, numpy, matrix

In R, you can use `outer` function to compute the outer product of the matrix, but can also use other operations, such as `FUN="-"` to operate subtractions. Is it feasible to do the same in Python and maybe NumPy or Pandas?

So I look for the equivalent to this R code:

```
outer(x, y, FUN="-")
```

In `numpy.outer`, you can compute the outer product by writing something like `numpy.outer(x, y)` as can in R code, but as far as I know, there are no other argument permitted to make other operations, such as subtraction.

So how can I get it? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
In [152]: a = np.arange(5)

In [153]: b = np.arange(8)[::-1]

In [154]: a
Out[154]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [155]: b
Out[155]: array([7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0])

In [156]: a[:, None] - b
Out[156]: 
array([[-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0],
       [-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

Where the `a[:, None]` inserts an extra axis in `a` to make it a vertical array (can also be done by `a.reshape(-1, 1)`).  Thus it is automatically [broadcasted](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to match `b`.

```
In [157]: a[:, None]
Out[157]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

To confirm the match:

```
> a = 0:4
> b = 7:0
> outer(a, b, FUN="-")
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]   -7   -6   -5   -4   -3   -2   -1    0
[2,]   -6   -5   -4   -3   -2   -1    0    1
[3,]   -5   -4   -3   -2   -1    0    1    2
[4,]   -4   -3   -2   -1    0    1    2    3
[5,]   -3   -2   -1    0    1    2    3    4
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't come up with using broadcasting! That looks cool and reasonable, thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [numpy.ufunc.outer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html). With the same vectors as in the previous answer:

```
In [3]: a = np.arange(5)
In [4]: b = np.arange(8)[::-1]
In [5]: np.subtract.outer(a,b)
Out[5]:
array([[-7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0],
       [-6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1],
       [-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2],
       [-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4]])
```